# Stack Overflow restarted my account

Tags: support

I had a account with 500 reputation, now when I log in it tells me how to start an account and I have 1 reputation and no previous questions. How is this possible?

Answer (score 40):

Your previous account was deleted because it was very obviously a sock puppet used to inflate the reputation of the (now suspended) [jasmine825](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6625785/jasmine825) account.

Which you should have known about, since we deleted this same account twice for doing the same thing and have suspended the main account twice. You're not even changing the names on these puppet accounts.

If there's any indication that this account is being used to circumvent the suspension of your main account, we will delete it again and impose more serious measures here.

Comment: Isn't the existence of the new account enough of an indication that OP is circumventing the suspension?

Comment: @Stijn Though it is rare, but could not it be that anyone trying to close the main account which is now suspended?

Comment: I removed that account, because I didnt need it anymore, how is that an issue if i made a new one?

Comment: @jazzyy22 - Of the three accounts here, one was created, used to vote for your main account, and deleted by a moderator. A second was created, used to vote for your main account, and deleted again by a moderator. Your main account still exists, and we're not going to remove that just so you can dodge a suspension. I've let this account survive long enough for you to read this and understand what you did wrong.

Comment: What does one earn by faking rep this way? (Other than all the joy of deleted accounts and suspensions) I mean it takes a lot more effort to disguise the "buddy" accounts than to write a couple of good answers, so in my eyes, earning rep this way is not a gain but a loss...

Comment: lol okay then just delete it im not signing in back here anyway

Comment: @ppeterka - The most common motivation is evasion of question bans by artificially making sure the posts of these accounts never dip into the negatives. Cleaning these up helps block future bad questions. Others try to use this to boost their employability in areas that judge you based on SO reputation, but that can backfire badly (in the last week, at least one person has begged us to unsuspend them at least for the duration of their job interview).

Comment: @BradLarson `in the last week, at least one person has begged us to unsuspend them at least for the duration of their job interview` Oh My Good Lord. Wow. I wouldn't want to work at a place that rates someone based on how quick he/she can spot badly escaped regex, and know that java.util.Date has the months indexed from 0, but days from 1... (At least I feel some 90% of my rep comes out of that...) As an interviewer, I would surely take a look at not only the number, but what's behind.

Comment: @ppeterka I think the catch is that an SO profile won't necessarily *get* you the job. But a suspended profile that you put on your resume will certainly *prevent* you from getting the job. IOW, if someone advertises their SO profile during a job search, it better be good.